# disable ALL virtual desktops?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to disable ALL virtual desktops in windows 10? I don'
t need them and a couple times now they've completely taken me away from my games. I want to literally disable this feature entirely so there's only a single desktop, how would I do this? A google search has not provided any answer

Comment: You cannot disable the shortcut so it's best to learn not to use it.